# Unable to add the task to listview in my tasks app

Tags: java, android

So I am working on a tasks app. I am trying to set up a functionality, that might sound a little complicated, but I want to put it to work. Hear me out : User types in a task name, and then clicks on an 'add subtask ' button. That takes him to another activity, where he types in his subtask name (edit text), and also tells me the priority of the task, and the amount of time it will take (users answers this in the form of radio buttons). Then, he clicks on the 'done' button, from which he is taken back to the previous activity, where he entered the task name. What I want, is that the subtask name, along with symbols of the priority and time are shown in a list there. I transfer the data of the subtask activity using intents, then I have also made a subtask object, which accepts the subtask name, and boolean values of the radio buttons. I also made a custom adapter class for my listview. But the issue is, it is just not showing. This is my code :

The subtask object class :

```
public class subtask {

    private String subtaskName;
    private boolean priHigh;
    private boolean priMed;
    private boolean priLow;
    private boolean timeMore;
    private boolean timeMed;
    private boolean timeLess;

    public subtask(String subtaskName, boolean priHigh, boolean priMed, boolean priLow, boolean timeMore, boolean timeMed, boolean timeLess) {
        this.subtaskName = subtaskName;
        this.priHigh = priHigh;
        this.priMed = priMed;
        this.priLow = priLow;
        this.timeMore = timeMore;
        this.timeMed = timeMed;
        this.timeLess = timeLess;
    }

    public String getSubtaskName() {
        return subtaskName;
    }

    public boolean isPriHigh() {
        return priHigh;
    }

    public boolean isPriMed() {
        return priMed;
    }

    public boolean isPriLow() {
        return priLow;
    }

    public boolean isTimeMore() {
        return timeMore;
    }

    public boolean isTimeMed() {
        return timeMed;
    }

    public boolean isTimeLess() {
        return timeLess;
    }
}
```

The adapter class :

```
public class SubtaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<subtask> {


    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<subtask> values;


    public SubtaskAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<subtask> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.subtask_item, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subtask_item, parent, false);

        TextView tvSubtaskName = rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtaskName);
        ImageView ivPri = rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivPri);
        ImageView ivTime = rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivTime);

        tvSubtaskName.setText(values.get(position).getSubtaskName());

        if (values.get(position).isPriHigh())
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_high);
        }
        else if (values.get(position).isPriMed())
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_med);
        }
       else if (values.get(position).isPriLow())
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_low);
        }

        if (values.get(position).isTimeMore())
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_more);
        }
        else if (values.get(position).isTimeMed())
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_med);
        }
        else if (values.get(position).isTimeLess())
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_less);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Here I receive the input from the subtasks activity and try and put it in the listview :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == ENTER_SUBTASK)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String subtaskName = data.getStringExtra("subtaskName");
                boolean priHigh = data.getBooleanExtra("priHigh", false);
                boolean priMed = data.getBooleanExtra("priMed", false);
                boolean priLow = data.getBooleanExtra("priLow", false);
                boolean timeMore = data.getBooleanExtra("timeMore", false);
                boolean timeMed = data.getBooleanExtra("timeMed", false);
                boolean timeLess = data.getBooleanExtra("timeLess", false);

                subtask subtask = new subtask(subtaskName, priHigh, priMed, priLow, timeMore, timeMed, timeLess);
                subtaskList.add(subtask);
                SubtaskAdapter adapter = new SubtaskAdapter(this, subtaskList);
                lvSubtasks.setAdapter(adapter);



            }

        }


    }
```

xml for the main activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".TaskInfo">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="163dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/floating_hint_taskname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:counterEnabled="true"
                app:counterMaxLength="20"
                app:counterTextColor="@color/white"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FlotatingHintStyle">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etTaskName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:hint="@string/name_your_task"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="#B8AEAE"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvSubtasks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNewSubtask"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text="@string/add_subtask" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvEnterTime"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="@string/estimated_working_time"
                    android:textColor="#B8AEAE"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/floating_hint_time_hrs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FlotatingHintStyle">


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etWorkingHrs"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                            android:hint="@string/hours"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="2"
                            android:textColorHint="#B8AEAE"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/floating_hint_time_mins"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FlotatingHintStyle">


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etWorkingMins"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                            android:hint="@string/minutes"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="2"
                            android:textColorHint="#B8AEAE"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvMaxTimeWithoutBreak"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="@string/time_you_can_work_for_without_a_break"
                    android:textColor="#B8AEAE"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/floating_hint_time_hours"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FlotatingHintStyle">


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etWorkingHours"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                            android:hint="@string/hours"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="2"
                            android:textColorHint="#B8AEAE"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/floating_hint_time_minutes"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/FlotatingHintStyle">


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etWorkingMinutes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                            android:hint="@string/minutes"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:maxLength="2"
                            android:textColorHint="#B8AEAE"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvBreakDuration"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="@string/break_duration"
                    android:textColor="#B8AEAE"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivLeft"
                        android:layout_width="56dp"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:longClickable="false"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvBreakTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivRight"
                        android:layout_width="56dp"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:longClickable="false"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_right" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post your xml too and did you try debugging, is adapter initialised and lvSubtasks.setAdapter is called?

Comment: I'll post my xml right now. No, not yet.. Actually, I have been trying to do this using different methods without any help. This time I got frustrated and finally asked online..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, your viewInflation logic is wrong and currently you aren't recycling the views, so make the following amendments in your `SubtaskAdapter` class

```
    public SubtaskAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<subtask> list) {

        //since your are using custom view,pass zero and inflate the custom view by overriding getview

        super(context, 0 , list);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = list;
    }

   @Override
       public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        
        //check if its null, if so inflate it, else simply reuse it
        if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subtask_item, parent, false);
        }

        //use convertView to refer the childviews to populate it with data
        TextView tvSubtaskName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtaskName);
        ImageView ivPri = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPri);
        ImageView ivTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivTime);

        tvSubtaskName.setText(values.get(position).getSubtaskName());

        if (values.get(position).isPriHigh())
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_high);
        }
        else if (values.get(position).isPriMed())
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_med);
        }
       else if (values.get(position).isPriLow())
        {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_low);
        }

        if (values.get(position).isTimeMore())
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_more);
        }
        else if (values.get(position).isTimeMed())
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_med);
        }
        else if (values.get(position).isTimeLess())
        {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_less);
        }
        
        //return the view you inflated
        return convertView;
    }

//to keep adding the new subtasks try the following
       public addANewSubTask(subtask newSubTask){
           ArrayList<subtask> newvalues = new ArrayList<subtask>(this.values);
           newvalues.add(newSubTask);
           this.values = newvalues
           notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

make the following amedements in `onActivityResult`

```
  subtask subtask = new subtask(subtaskName, priHigh, priMed, priLow, timeMore, timeMed, timeLess);
  adapter.addANewSubTask(subtask)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I am running it, the app crashes, saying :         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.taskmasterv3.TaskInfo.onActivityResult(TaskInfo.java:181)

Comment: it seems `subtaskList` is empty, have you initialized it properly?

Comment: Got my mistake. Works now. But still there is a problem. I am only able to enter one subtask. After that, it doesn't show. I think this is because I have entered the name of the object 'subtask' when I receive data. Is there any way this can keep happening as long as I want to.. I mean, to enter as many subtasks as I want?

Comment: add `addANewSubTask` in your adapter and see if it work, check the answer for more info

Comment: right now in your `onActivityResult` you are creating a new instance of `subtask` and an `adapter` and therefore all the old subtasks are gone and only the recent one is shown, instead just add the recent `subtask` to the existing adapter and call `notifydatasetchanged`

Comment: Hi, I tried adding it, but the variable 'list' is coming up in red, and it says it can't resolve that symbol

Comment: sorry, my bad, use `values` as that's the one which stores the `subtask`

Comment: No man. Still doesn't work. I am still only able to add only one subtask..

Comment: try uploading the MainActivity class too

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR STICKING AROUND! I This would not have been possible without you! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues

1. I would suggest to initialise adapter at start of your code and then use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to populate new data.
2. `public class subtask`, If you are using Java, your class names are not consistent with java standard programming style. Try renaming it to SubTask.
3. You can show more entries by overriding the default getCount method

> @Override public int getCount() {    return values.size(); }

4. The main problem in your code is

> ```
>  if (resultCode == ENTER_SUBTASK)
>     {
>        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
> ```

You are using resultCode for both, You might need to change

```
resultCode == ENTER_SUBTASK
```

to

```
requestCode == ENTER_SUBTASK
```

Further information can be found at

[Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: Thanks, but when I am running it, the app crashes, saying :        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference at com.example.taskmasterv3.TaskInfo.onActivityResult(TaskInfo.java:181)

Comment: Also, I did not understand what you mean to initialise the adapter at the start of my code.

Comment: @Aadhitya SubtaskAdapter adapter = new SubtaskAdapter(this, subtaskList); use this code at start and then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); whenever you add items to ur array.

Comment: Got my mistake. Works now. But still there is a problem. I am only able to enter one subtask. After that, it doesn't show. I think this is because I have entered the name of the object 'subtask' when I receive data. Is there any way this can keep happening as long as I want to.. I mean, to enter as many subtasks as I want?

Comment: Should I use that line of code in the adapter class?

Comment: yes and also add the function made by @rcs in his answer

Comment: No dude, still not working. I am still only able to add one subtask only.

Comment: perhaps share ur sample git code for more details

Comment: Please try debugging, without seeing the changes in your code it is hard. You must be adding multiple entries.

Comment: IT WORKED! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR STICKING AROUND! I This would not have been possible without you! Thank you!

Comment: If your query is resolved, you can accept the answer. Happy coding